# Why is the ContactNode causing problems to my codeEntry's later on?

Tags: java

I keep getting this message from the compiler, this is my code, it is supposed to print a person name, phone number and birthday. And I'm supposed to use the class Contact node in order for the program to work but I don't really understand how it works. This part is supposed to before the contact nodes but it wouldn't let me paste it on the enter code line for some reason:
"

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ContactList {

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  String fullName;
  String phoneNumber;
  String birthDay;   

  ContactNode contactEntry1;
  ContactNode contactEntry2;
  ContactNode contactEntry3;
  ContactNode currContactEntry;

  System.out.println("Person 1");
  System.out.println("Enter name:");
  fullName = scnr.nextLine();

  System.out.println("Enter phone number:");
  phoneNumber = scnr.nextLine();

  System.out.println("Enter birthday:");
  birthDay = scnr.nextLine();

  System.out.println("You entered: " + fullName + ", " + phoneNumber + ", " + birthDay);

  //First contact node (head of list)
  contactEntry1 = new ContactNode(fullName, phoneNumber, birthDay);

  System.out.println("");
  System.out.println("Person 2");
  System.out.println("Enter name:");
  fullName = scnr.nextLine();

  System.out.println("Enter phone number:");
  phoneNumber = scnr.nextLine();

  System.out.println("Enter birthday: ");
  birthDay = scnr.nextLine();

  System.out.println("You entered: " + fullName + ", " + phoneNumber + ", " + birthDay);

  contactEntry2 = new ContactNode(fullName, phoneNumber , birthDay);
  contactEntry1.insertAfter(contactEntry2);

  System.out.println("");
  System.out.println("Person 3");
  System.out.println("Enter name:");
  fullName = scnr.nextLine();

  System.out.println("Enter phone number:");
  phoneNumber = scnr.nextLine();

  System.out.println("Enter birthday:");
  birthDay  = scnr.nextLine();

  System.out.println("You entered: " + fullName + ", " + phoneNumber);

  contactEntry3 = new ContactNode(fullName, phoneNumber);
  contactEntry2.insertAfter(contactEntry3);

  System.out.println("");
  System.out.println("CONTACT LIST");

  currContactEntry = contactEntry1;

  while (currContactEntry != null) {
     currContactEntry.printContactNode();
     currContactEntry = currContactEntry.getNext();
     System.out.println("");
  }

  return;
```

}
}

`/tmp/java_abImvG/ContactList.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
      ContactNode contactEntry1;
      ^
  symbol:   class ContactNode
  location: class ContactList
/tmp/java_abImvG/ContactList.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
      ContactNode contactEntry2;
      ^
  symbol:   class ContactNode
  location: class ContactList
/tmp/java_abImvG/ContactList.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
      ContactNode contactEntry3;
      ^
  symbol:   class ContactNode
  location: class ContactList
/tmp/java_abImvG/ContactList.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
      ContactNode currContactEntry;
      ^
  symbol:   class ContactNode
  location: class ContactList
/tmp/java_abImvG/ContactList.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
      contactEntry1 = new ContactNode(fullName, phoneNumber, birthDay);
                          ^
  symbol:   class ContactNode
  location: class ContactList
/tmp/java_abImvG/ContactList.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
      contactEntry2 = new ContactNode(fullName, phoneNumber , birthDay);
                          ^
  symbol:   class ContactNode
  location: class ContactList
/tmp/java_abImvG/ContactList.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
      contactEntry3 = new ContactNode(fullName, phoneNumber);
                          ^
  symbol:   class ContactNode
  location: class ContactList
7 errors`

Comment: How are you trying to compile this?

Comment: @JoeC Im trying to compile this through the command prompt, Im just trying to see what my code outputs.

Comment: ...with what command?

Comment: @JoeC I'm sorry if I was not clear Im not trying to do anything special with the command, its just that everytime I run this code, I keep getting the same errors over and over when I run it.